# Is the intersection of people killed by Cell and Majin Buu still dead?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z

According to the rules of the earth Dragon Balls, a person can only be brought back to life once. Do the people that Majin Buu and Cell (or any other two villains) both killed remain dead despite the wishes used to bring them back? Or do these rules only apply to main characters?

It's been a long time since I watched the Majin Buu saga, but I do recall that Buu killed many people and destroyed the planet. I'm asking this question because I don't recall Goku and friends ever expressing any concern that some people wouldn't be able to be revived because they were killed twice (again, haven't seen it in a long time, so I can't be sure).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.
The people killed by Cell were brought back due to a wish granted by Shenron.
The second wish however to bring back the people who died in the Majin Buu saga was granted by Porunga who has no limitations regarding the number of times a person can be brought back to life.
Source : [Dragon Ball](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_(object)#Dragon_Ball_Z)